# Assign random picked color with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance, math

I have a grid in my page that I want to populate via javascript with 200 elements. The actual code that populate the `.grid` element is the following:

```
$(function () {
  var $gd = $(".grid");

  var blocks="";
  for(i=0; i < 200; i++){
    blocks += '<div class="block"></div>';
  }
  $gd.append(blocks);
});
```

What I'm trying to do now is assign to each element created a random picked color from a list.  Lets say red, blue, yellow, green (unexpected eh?). I'd like the values to be the most random possible, and also to avoid the same color to be picked again twice consequentially (just to be clear, it's ok something like `red-blue-red-green-blue` and so on, **NOT** `red-red-green-yellow`).

Maybe this can help in the randomize process, [Fisher–Yates Shuffle](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/), but I don't how to implement the non-twice adjacent rule stated above (if it is possible to apply at all).

What would be the best way to achieve this result? I'm also wondering if I could apply a gradient to each `.block` instead of a flat hex color; I guess the better route for this would be to assign a random class to each element mapped in CSS for the gradient and so on..

If the above script can be optimized performance-wise, I apreciate any suggestions!

Additional info:

- I'm using jQuery
- The grid is composed with 20 elements per row, for 10 rows
- The colors should be 4, but can be raised to 5-7 adding some neutral grey tones if it can help

**Here is a pen to experiment with** http://codepen.io/Gruber/pen/lDxBw/

*Bonus feature request:* as stated above I'd like to avoide duplicate adjacent colors. Is it possible to avoid this also "above and below"? I guess its very hard if not impossible to totally avoid this, but well if anyone can find a solution it would be awesome!
Something like this, where the "nope" marked element is prevented, while the "yep" diagonal marked are allowed:

[image]

Comment: In the end, all answer brought interesting solutions and ideas for other stuff I'm working on, but indeed @phil-h solution is the most ingenious for solving this. The pen I posted is updated with his code plus a couple enhancement for responsiveness and gradients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: randomColours.png]

The first thing I'd like to introduce is a filtered indexing function.

Given an array:

```
var options = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'purple', 'yellow']; // never less than 3!
```

And a filter:

```
function filterFunc(val) { 
   var taken = { 'red': 1,  'blue': 1 };
   return taken[val] ? 0 : 1;
}
```

We can take the nth item from the values permitted (==1) by the filter (not a quick way to do it, but until there is a performance constraint...):

```
// filteredIndex returns nth (0-index) element satisfying filterFunc
//   returns undefined if insufficient options
function filteredIndex(options, filterFunc, n) {
   var i=-1, j=0;
   for(;j<options.length && i<n; ++j) {
     i += filterFunc(options[j]);
     if(i==n)
       break;
   }
   return options[j];
}
```

So now we can pick up a value with index 2 in the filtered list. If we don't have enough options to do so, we should get `undefined`.

If you are populating the colours from, say, the top left corner, you can use as few as 3 colours, as you are only constrained by the cells above and to the left.

To pick randomly, we need to set up the filter. We can do that from a list of known values thus:

```
function genFilterFunc(takenValues) {
   var takenLookup = {};
   for(var i=0; i < takenValues.length; ++i) {
      takenLookup[takenValues[i]] = 1;
   }
   var filterFunc = function(val) {
     return takenLookup[val] ? 0 : 1;
   };
   return filterFunc;
}
```

We can choose a random colour, then, for a cell in a `grid[rows][cols]`:

```
function randomColourNotUpOrLeft(grid, row, col, options, ignoreColour) {
  var takenlist = [];
  if(row > 0 && grid[row-1][col] != ignoreColour) {
    takenlist.push(grid[row-1][col]);
  }
  if(col > 0 && grid[row][col-1] != ignoreColour) {
    takenlist.push(grid[row][col-1]);
  }
  var filt = genFilterFunc(takenlist);
  var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random()*(options.length-takenlist.length));
  var randomColour = filteredIndex(options, filt, randomIndex);
  return randomColour;
}
```

Note here that the random index used depends on how many colours have been filtered out; if there are 4 left we can have 0-3, but if only 2 are left it must be 0-1, etc. When the adjacent cells are the same colour and/or we are near the boundary, there is less constraint about which colour is chosen. Finally fill in a grid:

```
function fillGridSpeckled(grid, options, nullColour) {
  for(var row=0; row<grid.length; ++row) {
    for(var col=0; col<grid[row].length; ++col) {
      grid[row][col] = randomColourNotUpOrLeft(grid,row,col,options,nullColour);
    }
  }
}
```

I've put it all in [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/qoyar/4/edit), along with a few bits to demo the code working.

[image: randomColours.png]

Comment: Thank you for your willingness, the result is indeed what I'm trying to obtain! I have a question though: why have you used a `canvas` to draw the elements? I know that it is indeed the most apropriate way to proceed, but I'd prefer an old plain crapload of injected `div`s in my page for better browser support and the possibility to assign a class to each so that I can map their styles via CSS. Is it possible to change your code in this way?

Comment: Also can you explain me briefly that `for(;` in the `filteredIndex` function? In particular I don't get what that semicolon right after the round bracket means, sorry I'm still quite a novice in javascript (a nice euphemism for "darn n00b" :P)

Comment: Slowly grasping better your code, I understand `canvas` is (I guess) necessary to create a layout with no vertical duplicates. In this case  what would you suggest as possibilities to fill the squares with gradients instead of flat colors? I'm a bit concerned about performance in drawing those 200~ squares with gradients and strokes.. or is this not an issue at all?

Comment: @Gruber: Sorry, just seen these comments. You don't have to use canvas; I'm not very jquery aware so do just change the code that draws to canvas to instead set the colour via jquery in your code, at least to test it.

Comment: @Gruber: The `for(;` is because a `for` construct requires three statements inside the bracket: init, test and increment. Since I need the `j` variable outside the loop at the end, I've taken the `var j=0` statement out of the loop init and put it on the previous line. Not strictly necessary in javascript as `var` declares things at the function-level scope, but I'm used to C++ where declarations are block-level.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(function () {
  var colors = ["red","blue","green","yellow"];
  var $gd = $(".grid");
  var previousColor;
  var blocks="";
  for(i=0; i < 200; i++){
    var color = "";
    while(color === previousColor) {
        color= colors [Math.floor(Math.random()*colors .length)];
    }
    blocks += '<div class="block" style="color:' + color + '"></div>';
    previousColor = color;
  }
  $gd.append(blocks);
});
```

Comment: this isn't a perfect solution as it won't prevent repeated colors vertically, but it might be a good place to start.

Comment: The `while` statement is indeed a good point, though it goes with weird results, as it will leave a blank element after each colored one. I've slightly edited yuor code to use `background` instead of `color`.
No worries for the vertical colors, that is a bonus feature request, it would be awesome to have but is not really mandatory!
I'll update my question with a fiddle to use for 
experimentation

Answer (score 3):

First, I'd use classes for the colors:

CSS:

```
.red { background-color: red; }
.blue { background-color: blue; }
.green { background-color: green; }
.yellow { background-color: yellow; }
```

And then here's the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var colors = ["red","blue","green","yellow"];
  var $gd = $(".grid");
  var previousColor;
  var previousRow;
  var rowSize = 10;
  while(rowSize--) previousRow.push("none");
  var blocks = "";
  for(i=0; i < 200; i++){
    var color = colors [Math.floor(Math.random()*colors .length)];
    while((color == previousColor) || (color == previousRow[i%rowSize])) {
        color = colors [Math.floor(Math.random()*colors .length)];
    }
    blocks += '<div class="block ' + color + '"></div>';
    previousColor = color;
    previousRow[i%rowSize] = color;
  }
  $gd.append(blocks);
});
```

I started off with something similar to MikeB's code but added a row element so we know what is above your current block.